# Parameters passed in cucumber feature file, not working in step defination script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

Query: Parameters passed in cucumber feature file, not working in step defination script. I tried to pass browser name from cucumber and script should  run as per inputs.
Below is the feature file and step definition which expected to work

```
    Feature: List of scenarios.

      Scenario Outline: Add a Bank in application
        Given Open "browser" and enter a URL
        When Login to application and navigate to bank master
        Then Click on create bank and enter "Code" and "Short name" and "Description" save details
        Then Logout and Approve the Bank from checker
        Then Verify the bank is added successfully
        Then Logout the application and close the browser

    Examples: 
          | browser | Code  | Short name | Description     |
          | chrome  | Bank2 | Bank Two   | Bank Two Desc   |
          | Firefox | Bank3 | Bank Three | Bank Three Desc |

    **Step Defination is:**

    @Given("^Open (.*). and enter a URL$")
        public void open_and_enter_a_URL(String browser) throws Throwable {
            // 'firefox'
            if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", ProjectPath+"/Drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            // 'chrome'
            else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ProjectPath+"/Drivers/chromedriver.exe"); 
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            } // 'Edge'
            else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) { // set path to Edge.exe
                System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", ProjectPath+"/Drivers/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
            } else {
                // If no browser passed throw exception
                throw new Exception(**"Browser is not correct");**
                 //Giving this error for incorrect browser as parameter is not identified in step defination 
            }
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(URL);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

 **Getting error as:**
    java.lang.Exception: Browser is not correct
        at.stepDefination.addbankSteps.open_and_enter_a_URL(addbankSteps.java:42)
        at ✽.Given Open chrome and enter a URL(Features/TC_001.feature:4)
```

Can someone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Feature file you need to give browsername like chrome, firefox, IE and not text "browser"

Feature: List of scenarios.

```
  Scenario Outline: Add a Baak in Liquidice
    Given Open firefox and enter a URL
```

Comment: That also not working, but if I wanted to send browser name as a prameters then can I send in same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Double-quotes are not required in the feature file if you are using (.*) regular expression in the step definition. Please make sure to use cucumber 4.x.x or above and update the plugins and the IDE.

**Feature File:**

```
Feature: List of scenarios.

  Scenario Outline: Add a Bank in application
    Given Open browser and enter a URL
```

**Step Definition:**

```
@Given("Open (.*) and enter a URL")
```